# Firehose to S3: What happens to data after unsuccessful tries for 24 hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-firehose

From AWS documentation:

> Data delivery to your S3 bucket might fail for reasons such as the
>   bucket doesn’t exist anymore, the IAM role that Kinesis Firehose
>   assumes doesn’t have access to the bucket, network failure, or similar
>   events. Under these conditions, Kinesis Firehose keeps retrying for up
>   to 24 hours until the delivery succeeds. The maximum data storage time
>   of Kinesis Firehose is 24 hours and **your data is lost if data delivery
>   fails for more than 24 hours**.

- Now what happens to data that is lost?
- Are there any logs or metrics to check for such failures?

I have created alarm on **DeliverytoS3.Success** metrics (if metric value < 1 for 1 min, alarm triggers). So whenever there is a failure while sending to S3, it retries till 24 hrs but metrics show value < 1 for that period and alarm triggers. Also I am not seeing any CloudWatch error (S3Delivery) logs.

My aim is to trigger alarm only when we are not able to send data to S3 ultimately (even after 24 hrs).

**Note:** Please let me know if any explanation or correction is required.

Comment: I still haven't found any metric to track whether data is lost. However I was able to correct the alarm to not send false alarms by increasing the observation time 30 mins instead of 1min. And therefore trusting firehose reliability.
Its been 4 days and no false alarms yet.

Comment: I think it would be better to rely on this metric : "DeliveryToS3.DataFreshness". The value should be consistent if Firehose is able to deliver data to S3 properly. As soon as there's an error, this should spike.